# PHP's mysql migration to mysqli performance

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently I am in the process of migrating a legacy code base to PHP 7.1.
The code base uses a single database object as a wrapper around PHP's removed mysql-functions.
So the easy way seemed to be to simply replace all those mysql-functions for the new mysqli-functions.

No problems there...

However, when I enrolled the refactored code to the production server, the mysql server load went sky high.
So that's when I found out that `mysql_connect` tried to re-use mysql connections (or something like that):

> If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.

`mysqli_connect` does not have such behaviour, so indeed we saw a tremendous number of mysql connections being opened.

So then we fixed that by implementing mysqli object caching ourself. So when one request tries to open another connection to the same user/database combination, we re-use the already established connection instead.

That does make a big difference, however we still see a much higher database load (about 5 times higher).

Am I still missing something here? Any great ideas?
Ofcourse the problems may still be specific to our code base, but I'm hoping there is simply something with the mysqli extension that I have overlooked.

Side note: we do not want to use persistent connections just now, because that may give other complications.

Comment: @bassxzero "_Side note: we do not want to use persistent connections just now, because that may give other complications._"

Comment: @bassxzero Uhh, no. The post hasn't been edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you still have an occasional orphan connection or two from each script. Make sure your code connects only once per instance.

> we fixed that by implementing mysqli object caching ourself.

In PHP, object caching is already implemented. You just have to make sure that only once connection is made and the just use the single object holding that connection throughout the script execution.

> we do not want to use persistent connections just now, because that may give other complications.

Exactly. Having zillions connects in one script, persistent connection will kill your database in an instant.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I know that all objects are references in PHP. I just meant we keep only one mysqli connection in the database object, just like you say.
However you may be right that there are "occasional orphan connections" somewhere (although I doubt that), I will look into that.

Can you clarify the "Having zillions connects in one script, persistent connection will kill your database in an instant" part a bit? Is it meant sarcastically?

Comment: I have just double-checked: there are no "occasional orphan connections". All code uses the same database wrapper class, and that class now has a static array containing the connection. So there cannot be more connections to the same database.
We have also monitored that with XDebug (in development) and can confirm that.

Comment: I just posted an answer to my own question, because apparently nothing is wrong with our code after all. However, I am still curious about your insights on using persistent connections. I read that by default PHP will execute a reset function for each reuse of a persistent connection: is that the "will kill your database in an instant" that you are mentioning?

Comment: it's simple. given that initially you had a lot of connections from each instance, each HTTP process would take over a lot of persistent connections as well, instantly causing too many connections error. It should be not a problem if your code opens only one connection per execution.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this is dumb: yesterday I checked out the refactored code base on the production server and almost instantly I saw the mysql server load raise about 5 times the average.

So I reverted the code and the server load dropped back to average and below.

Then I checked out the new code again and the server load again raised to about 4 times the average. That's when I concluded that something was wrong with our code.

Today I tried again and nothing happens: the server load stays on average and below. So yesterday I have been looking at visitor peaks instead.
Caching the mysqli connections in a static array did fix the problems after all.